# How best to deploy slightly different applications across many VM's

Tags: linux

I have a full stack application that runs on multiple VM's - each VM is a different site. I push changes to the application repo weekly and want to automate the process of deployment to save me time of SSHing into each VM and configuring it by hand every time.

The tricky part is that each site is slightly different in some high level configuration files like defining the site location in the settings.py file.

What is the best CICD tool for deploying and modifying the application to each VM?

Thanks!

Comment: Is **configuration files** the only difference between instances? Or is some code or branch different too?

Comment: Just the configuration files!

Comment: I've done something similar by writing a Bash script that checkouts the code, changes the config file according to each instance needs then copies the whole thing over though SFTP. I've used Jenkins for automating that, but pretty much any tool would do, the main thing is to get a whole .sh file right doing all the heavy work.